# Agregar una clase a elementos excepto al ultimo

Tags: jquery, html

Tengo divs que se generan dinámicamente con un botón. Ya puede generarlos con el siguiente script:

```
var contenedor = $(".inputs");
$(".agregar").click(function(e){            
    add_control(contenedor);
    $(".agregar, .nth").hide(); 
    e.preventDefault();         
});

function add_control(contenedor){
    ctr = ctr + 1;
    contenedor.append('<div class="btun"><input type="text" class="ed" value=""  id="tb' + ctr + '' +'"/>'+
                              '<button class="agregar_in">+</button>'+
                              '<button class="eliminar_in">-</button></div>');
    console.log(ctr);
}
```

Hasta ahí todo bien, ahora esto, como pueden observar, genera dos botones.

Mi pregunta es, como puedo deshabilitar el botón con la clase `agregar_in` que genero si doy dos o mas veces clic, es decir,

```
<button class="agregar">+</button>
<div class="inputs"></div>
<div class="btun">
        <input type="text" class="e" value id="tb1">
        <button class="agregar_in">+</button>
        <button class="eliminar_in">-</button>
</div>
<div class="btun">
        <input type="text" class="e" value id="tb2">
        <button class="agregar_in">+</button>
        <button class="eliminar_in">-</button>
</div>
```

En este caso, sería el que se encuentra después de tb1 (deshabilitar)

Comment: Si ocultas el botón con clase `.agregar` (que no aparece en tu ejemplo) como es posible que generes dos botones? Cual es el valor de la variable `contenedor`? Edita la pregunta y agrega el código faltante?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu ejemplo esta incompleto pero creo que la solución esta cerca de este código que te pongo.

Primero para deshabilitar el botón lo haces agregando el atributo `disabled` pero para seleccionar el correcto(según la pregunta el último) debes usar el selector [`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)

```
$(".agregar_in:last").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Además debes recordar que si deshabilitaste alguno antes debes volverlo a habilitar

```
$(".agregar_in").removeAttr("disabled");
```

Este es el código

```js
$(function() {
  var ctr = 0;
  var contenedor = $('#contenedor');

  $(".agregar").click(function(e) {
    add_control(contenedor);
    //$(".agregar, .nth").hide();
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".agregar_in").removeAttr("disabled");
    $(".agregar_in:last").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  });

  function add_control(contenedor) {
    ctr = ctr + 1;
    contenedor.append('<div class="btun"><input type="text" class="ed" value=""  id="tb' + ctr + '' + '"/>' +
      '<button class="agregar_in">+</button>' +
      '<button class="eliminar_in">-</button></div>');
    console.log(ctr);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contenedor">
  <button class="agregar">Agregar boton</button>

</div>
```

Si lo que quieres es solo habilitar el último usa el selector [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) en conjunto con `:last`

```js
$(function() {
  var ctr = 0;
  var contenedor = $('#contenedor');

  $(".agregar").click(function(e) {
    add_control(contenedor);
    //$(".agregar, .nth").hide();
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".agregar_in").removeAttr("disabled");
    $(".agregar_in:not(:last)").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  });

  function add_control(contenedor) {
    ctr = ctr + 1;
    contenedor.append('<div class="btun"><input type="text" class="ed" value=""  id="tb' + ctr + '' + '"/>' +
      '<button class="agregar_in">+</button>' +
      '<button class="eliminar_in">-</button></div>');
    console.log(ctr);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contenedor">
  <button class="agregar">Agregar boton</button>

</div>
```

Comment: Gracias, el primer ejemplo fue correcto.